# Are there any downsides to receiving BSc, MSc, and PhD all from the same university?

Tags: phd, university

Like the title says, are there any downsides to receiving BSc, MSc, and PhD all from the same university?

My university is not very well known outside my home country. I did not enter the PhD program yet. If I would stay here, I would already have many good contacts (~10 professors/academics). Also, because I perform quite well, I assume I could get to do exactly what I want. On the other hand... I think I could get into Europe's top-ten universities.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is an obvious downside of staying at the same university—you will only work with one set of advisors and contacts throughout your career. That will mean that you may not benefit from the experience and diversity of viewpoints and philosophies that comes from working with different groups of people across the length of your career.

However, if there is a *compelling* reason to remain at your school, that's a different situation. This could be financial, personal, or educational. For instance, a family member may have a job that makes it difficult to relocate, or a new project may be starting up that provides a unique educational opportunity.

Beyond that, though, I would lean towards going somewhere else for your PhD program!

Comment: Good advice, @aeismail! But how can I get to another university? Is there any site to know about available PhD positions in foreign countries?

Comment: @gaussblurinc That's a very broad question and the answer depends on the field.  I would ask academics at your current location.

Comment: @gerrit actually, I am master in computer science and I would like to continue education, but not in my country

Comment: @gaussblurinc Right.  My recommendation stands, ask someone with domain specific knowledge for job boards and mailing lists.

Answer (score 6):

A top university has many advantages. Better universities provide better Professors, better academic environment, better scientific connection, better equipments, better laboratories, they can get better grants, they can give better scholarship, etc. You can find better friends and get better reputation.

@aeismail has very good points on the reason you may or may not stay in the same university for all your academic carrier.

Some universities has large department and so many professors. there is a chance you don't even know them yet after 6 years being there. They work on different fields and you can work on different field if you want. but that's not true for all universities.

Despite all of this, consider that you will carry your university names forever in your CV! This will affect your feature job opportunity a lot, in industry and mainly in academic world.

But as one my professor says: "*sky is the same color everywhere*" ;)

All said I suggest you going to a better university. At least try to.

Comment: What does he or she mean by *the sky is the same colour everywhere*?  (It's not even true).

Comment: He lectures me about finding the right teacher (guru) and go everywhere the science is. but then he says sky is the same color everywhere. and he means that you can do the same everywhere. The more important thing is *you*. no matter where you are you can be the best.